# Updating a table from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query down below which works. My question is I cant seem to alter it so it updates the LessonTaken field in Availability Table everytime unless StudentID=0. So only want it to update the field if the studentID <> 0;

```
UPDATE Availability SET LessonTaken = 'Y'
WHERE (
   SELECT LessonID
   FROM Lesson
   WHERE Availability.StudentID = Lesson.StudentID
);
```

The Tables are like so:

Availability:

AvailabilityID
StudentID
StartTime
EndTime
LessonTaken
NoOfFrees

Lesson:

LessonID
StudentID
StartTime
EndTime
DayOfWeek
LessonPaid.

I have a query which selects the student with the fewest frees, (selecting DayOfWeek, StartTime, EndTime) and inserts this into the LessonTable for the corresponding fields. This is for a timetabling programme. I hope this is clear, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does adding the condition you want help?

```
UPDATE Availability
    SET LessonTaken = 'Y'
WHERE Availability.studentID <> 0 AND
      (SELECT LessonID
       FROM Lesson
       WHERE Availability.StudentID = Lesson.StudentID
      );
```

Comment: It says Data type mismatch in expression?

Comment: Never mind I managed to fix it, this query worked many thanks, fixed the data type mismatch as studentID was short text for some reason, changing to number fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

This is for T-SQL, using join

```
update avail
    set LessonTaken = 'Y' 
from Availability avail
    join Lesson less on avail.StudentID = less.StudentID
where avail.StudentID <> 0
```

Good luck

Comment: Another person i think put something similar, not sure if MS-ACCESS accepted this variation of SQL or not, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this might sound silly, but have you tried:

```
UPDATE Availability SET LessonTaken = 'Y'
WHERE (SELECT LessonID
       FROM Lesson
       WHERE Availability.StudentID = Lesson.StudentID
       AND Lesson.StudentID != 0 
       );
```

?? Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi yes I've tried that, it doesn't like it one bit!

Comment: hmm :/ which StudentID should be 0? Av.SID or Les.SID?

Comment: Ive tried both but it should be Availability.StudentID <> 0 but it comes back with data type mismatch in expression when i add 'Availability.StudentID <> 0 ' anywhere in the query.

Comment: Never mind I managed to fix it, this query worked many thanks, fixed the data type mismatch as studentID was short text for some reason, changing to number fixed this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, sometimes the hardest problems have the easiest solutions haha!